# Should I try to fix the special case or just catch the stackoverflow Error in this case?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public boolean isConnected(int row, int col) {    //helper Method 
        int i;
        int j;

        if (BOARD[row][col].isEmpty())
            return false;
        for (i = row; i > 0; i--)
            if (hasRed(i, col))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(i, col))
                break;
        for (i = row; i < ROWS; i++)
            if (hasRed(i, col))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(i, col))
                break;
        for (i = col; i < COLS; i++)
            if (hasRed(row, i))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(row, i))
                break;
        for (i = col; i > 0; i--)
            if (hasRed(row, i))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(row, i))
                break;
        for (i = row, j = col; i > 0 && j < COLS; i--, j++)
            if (hasRed(i, j))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(i, j))
                break;
        for (i = row, j = col; i < ROWS && j > 0; i++, j--)
            if (hasRed(i, j))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(i, j))
                break;
        for (i = row, j = col; i > 0 && j > 0; i--, j--)
            if (hasRed(i, j))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(i, j))
                break;
        for (i = row, j = col; i < ROWS && j < COLS; i++, j++)
            if (hasRed(i, j))
                return true;
            else if (isEmpty(i, j))
                break;

        return false;

    }
```

//The main Method which may cause an exception the algorithm after many test cases tried always terminates if there is a true solution but may or may not terminate for a false one the reason I guess is that the recursion step does not simplify the original problem but actually expands it ! in order to have a chance to get the correct solution, the problem is that in certain conditions which certainly should return false the algorithm cannot terminate as it keep checking previously solved subproblems and so on.

```
public boolean isConnected2(int rowCurr, int colCurr) {

            if (rowCurr >= ROWS || rowCurr < 0 || colCurr < 0 || colCurr >= COLS) 
                return false;                  //Base case 1 reached bounds of the 2d array
            if (isEmpty(rowCurr, colCurr))
                return false;
            if (isConnected(rowCurr, colCurr)) // base case 2 current piece is connected according to the method above
                return true;

            else {
                return     isConnected2(rowCurr + 1, colCurr + 1)                                          
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr - 1, colCurr - 1)
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr + 1, colCurr - 1)
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr - 1, colCurr + 1)
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr - 1, colCurr - 1)
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr + 1, colCurr)
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr - 1, colCurr)
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr, colCurr + 1) 
                        || isConnected2(rowCurr, colCurr - 1);
// if any of the above calls returns true we are done


            }

        }
```

The thing is I am not sure how to handle the special cases that cause the algorithm to recurse to infinitely, And I am sure due to the nature of(||) operator that if there is a true solution IT WILL TERMINATE. So is it not better in this case to just handle the StackOverFlow error and treat it as a false return for the method ??

Comment: So you're going to rely on the VM blowing up instead of having a properly-terminating recursive function?!

Comment: You should not handle the `StackOverflowError`, but fix to avoid the same.

Comment: On the other hand, you've asked 14 questions and only accepted one answer, and only cast two votes in 10 months.  Why should we help you?

Comment: @Dave Newton it does seem kind of weird but that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't EVER leave a stack overflow in your program.  Letting it happen and catching it is a huge burden on the JVM.  Fix your recursion so that it can't happen.

Answer (score 3):

Any recursive function can be converted to a non-recursive function.

For example, use a queue of some kind. Push the different parameters to the `isConnected2` method onto the queue, and then continually pop a set of parameters from the queue, and evaluate them. If that evaluation results in what would have been more calls to the function, push a new set of parameters on to the queue. You can then terminate if the queue gets too large or after a certain length of time has passed.

This way you use the heap instead of the stack, and avoid the potential for a stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe better is to make the algorithm dynamic i.e the reason for infinite recursion is checking previously solved subproblems and treating them as brand new problems hence never terminating until a subproblem returns true.... so I can store the sub results in a structure and add the check in the base case it can drastically improve the efficiency too

Comment: @M.K Yes, you really should switch to dynamic programming here.

Comment: If you can't put an upper bound on the recursion depth, you should remove the recursion as well.

Comment: I finally was able to do it after adding a linked list of previously visited vertices and adding a check to return false if the current position was previously visited, worked like a charm THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isConnected2(int row, int col) {
        int i; int j;
        if (OutOfBounds(row, col)) 
            return false;
        if (isEmpty(row, col))
            return false;
        if (isConnected(row, col)) 
            return true;

        else {

            for (i = row; i > 0; i--)
                if(isConnected(i,col))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(i, col))
                    break;

            for (i = row; i < ROWS; i++)
                if(isConnected(i,col))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(i,col))
                    break;
            for (i = col; i < COLS; i++)
                if(isConnected(row,i))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(row,i))
                    break;
            for (i = col; i > 0; i--)
                if(isConnected(row,i))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(row,i))
                    break;
            for (i = row, j = col; i > 0 && j < COLS; i--, j++)
                if(isConnected(i,j))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(i,j))
                    break;
            for (i = row, j = col; i < ROWS && j > 0; i++, j--)
                if(isConnected(i,j))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(i,j))
                    break;
            for (i = row, j = col; i > 0 && j > 0; i--, j--)
                if(isConnected(i,j))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(i,j))
                    break;
            for (i = row, j = col; i < ROWS && j < COLS; i++, j++)
                if(isConnected(i,j))
                    return true;
                else if(isEmpty(i,j))
                    break;

        }
        return false;

    }
```

this is the same method isConnected2 implemented iteratively is it analogous ? and now it checks each direction in the 2d array only once instead of propagating in all directions repeatedly